# Is calling IntersectionObserver.unobserve() strictly required?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, code-cleanup, intersection-observer

Recently I've been using Intersection Observers in React (16.4+) as follows:

```
const myRef = React.useRef(null);

React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    doWork,
    { rootMargin: "0px 0px 0px 0px" }
  );

  observer.observe(myRef.current)
}, [])
```

Generally in React we're told to always return a cleanup function from our effect hooks if those hooks are setting up functions like `window.addEventListener`:

```
return () => window.removeEventListener('event', cb); // more cleanup
```

Should I be `unobserve`'ing `myRef.current` in a similar way? Or is that not strictly required in the same way it is for window event listeners?

I haven't found anything in the w3c spec regarding this, I've also been performance profiling my components and I haven't seen any negative results of not explicitly observing either.

Is there any consensus on this?

Comment: It might not be strictly required if the observed element is removed from the DOM anyway (unlike for installing listeners on globals like `window`), but yes it's definitely a best practice.

Comment: This SO post is more about MutationObservers, but the idea is similar: Don't worry too much about it, since it will be garbage collected when the DOM Element is removed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51106262/2661744

I guess it could be best practice to save some work for your garbage collector though.